# new thread in Titanium Hyperloop

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium, huawei-mobile-services, appcelerator-hyperloop, hyperloop

I want use Huawei Push Kit in my Appcelerator Titanium app with Hyperloop.

```
    var tokenString = '';
    var Activity = require('android.app.Activity');
    var ActivityToken = require('com.huawei.hms.aaid.HmsInstanceId');

try{    
        const activity = new Activity(Ti.Android.currentActivity);
        tokenString = ActivityToken.getInstance(activity).getToken(appID, "HCM");
        console.log('tokenString', tokenString); 
}
catch (e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

But I receive error: "operation in MAIN thread prohibited"

How do I run the code in a separate thread?

Comment: Could you try the [Automatic Initialization](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-client-dev-0000001050042041#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050042041__section13546121751811) to get the token? **ActivityToken.getInstance(activity).setAutoInitEnabled(true);** Token returned by using the **onNewToken(String token)** method in the customized class that inherits **HmsMessageService**.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Automatic Initialization](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-client-dev-0000001050042041#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050042041__section13546121751811?ha_source=hms1), by calling the **setAutoInitEnabled(boolean enable)** method in **HmsMessaging**.

```
ActivityToken.getInstance(activity).setAutoInitEnabled(true);
```

The applied token is returned through the **onNewToken()** method after completing the configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much! "setAutoInitEnabled" works. 
But how can I get a token using "onNewToken"? 
If I use:
 
`var ActivityToken = require('com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessaging');
const activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
ActivityToken.getInstance(activity).setAutoInitEnabled(true);
var ActivityGetToken = require('com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService');
ActivityGetToken.onNewToken();` 
I receive error: "ActivityGetToken.onNewToken is not a function". 

          If I use:  

`Titanium.App.addEventListener('onNewToken', function(e) {
  console.log('Ok!');
});`.

it never works.

Comment: If I use:


`var HmsMessageService = require('com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService');
   
var MyView = com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.extend({
 onNewToken: function(token) {
 this.super.onNewToken(token);
 console.log(token);
 }
});
var customView = new MyView(activity);`


I receive nothing.

Comment: @Tvik I am not aware of Appcelerator Titanium, about how to use **onNewToken()** method  on it. :(

Comment: I'm not sure if that works in hyperloop since hyperloop is creating things at runtime and you'll need a `service` that points to your class (check https://medium.com/huawei-developers/integrating-huawei-core-push-kit-90f24c8c5d29). Wouldn't it be a lot easier to wrap that as a module? Take an existing push module (e.g. ti.firebase) as a basis and adapt it to the Huawei module.

Comment: @shirley Could you tell me. How can I find out the current push token of the device without overload methods. Maybe there are some properties

Answer (score -1):

Wrap around the code inside background thread, since the error says clearly that this can not be run on main thread. Time consuming calls are usually not allowed in main thread, onCreate etc.

```
Thread { 
…
    }.run()
```

Comment: The question is specific to Hyperloop in Appcelerator Titanum. This syntax won't help there.